# Custom Loss Function Caffe (Spearman Coefficient) while FInetuning (Regression)

Tags: regression, caffe, conv-neural-network, loss, matcaffe

I am finetuning imagenet for a regression problem in caffe. At present I am using Eucliden Loss, but I don't think it is any good in my case.
I want the loss values to be the [spearman coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) between predicted labels and actual labels. How can I do so?

Please help!

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, in order to compute the Spearman Coefficient you need to rank (=sort) your predictions. Are you going to sort them globally? by batch? Given a batch and its predicted labels, would you be able to compute the Spearman Coefficient in, say, python?

Comment: I don't know about python, but given a vector of predicted labels and groundtruth labels, in matlab, I just use corr(predLables,groundLables,'Type','Spearman') for calculating rho.

Comment: and what is its derivative w.r.t the scores? I'm not sure it's differentiable

Comment: I lost you there, why do we need to have concern for derivatives and differentiability?

Comment: because you need the gradients for the optimization. you can't train without gradients: it's SGD: Stochastic GRADIENT Descent

Comment: ok, that means I can't use this as a loss function, guess I will have to do with mse.

Comment: there's hinge loss and l1 loss... there are quite a few to pick from...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As cleared in the comment section, since the loss function needs to be differentiable, and spearman coefficient isn't, we can't use it as a loss function.